# How to record human voice and display as text on command line?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, voice-dictation, speech

I am looking tool or a script that records human voice and displays as text *purely* on command line.

I am not looking for text to speech, but rather speech to text.

I do not want to work at all with a UI; all command line.

**EDIT :**

I am actually saying to record voice (speech) and displays on terminal.

Say my command is 'speak'

then when i do

```
$ speak
```

now whatever i speak is supposed to be printed like this.

say i speak. "I am application to record your voice and displays on the terminal"

should be visible as this :

```
$speak
I am application to record your voice and displays on the terminal
```

It should again wait for new words and print on the go.

Very similar as google does (BUT i want the same on command line) :
https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html

You can consider the same as VICE-VERCA of `say` command. `say` is `text-to-speech` but here i want `speech-to-text`

Comment: that is interesting. so how do you intend to speak the special symbols  in the command line ?

Comment: hi, please see my edit

Comment: So you want it to only display the spoken text, or you want it to execute commands based on spoken words.

Comment: Can You use builtin Dictation? I am able to dictate text into Terminal with this. Press twice `Fn` key to start dictation.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's terminal does this.

Press the function key twice to start dictation. If that doesn't work, open Speech and Dictation system preferences and enable it/select the sound input you prefer to dictate to.

Comment: Absolutely, I use this feature all the time